# s does not live long enough: borrowed value does not live long enough;

Tags: rust, split

I am new to Rust, and when using `split` and then assigning to a var, it gives the following problems.

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut prev_key: &str = "";

    for line in io::stdin().lines(){
        let s = line.unwrap();
        let data: Vec<&str> = s.split("\t").collect::<Vec<_>>();
        if prev_key.len() == 0 {
            prev_key = data[0];
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0597]: s does not live long enough
  --> src/reducer.rs:8:31
   |
8  |         let data: Vec<&str> = s.split("\t").collect::<Vec<_>>();
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
9  |         if prev_key.len() == 0 {
   |            -------------- borrow later used here
...
12 |     }
   |     - s dropped here while still borrowed
```

Comment: What is this trying to achieve? It looks like it grabs one line of something.

Comment: @tadman Hi!  It is the start of some programs. I just want to change the `prev_key` according to the input from stdin.

Comment: I can only loosely follow what you're trying to do. Why the split on tabs? Why get only the first entry? Do you need other entries? If you only care about the first one, why not just `next()` instead of `collect()` and then `[0]`?

Comment: @tadman  Yeah, the input line is joined by `\t`;  I just write the `if code` and in the `else code `, there will be other operations that use other entries;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might not want to use a string slice but a normal `String` instead.

```
let mut prev_key: String = String::from("");

for line in io::stdin().lines() {
    let s = line.unwrap();
    let data: Vec<&str> = s.split("\t").collect::<Vec<_>>();
    if prev_key.len() == 0 {
        prev_key = data[0].to_owned();
    }
}
```

The scope of `s` is only inside the `for` loop. `data` contains string slices of `s` which you can't directly assign to `prev_key` since `prev_key` outlives the `for` loop. So creating a copy of `data[0]` with `to_owned()` solves the assignment issue.

Comment: Personally would recommend `Option<String>` vs. a String that might be empty. Conveys the meaning a lot more concisely, as `priv_key.is_none()` leaves no ambiguity.

Comment: @tadman - that sounds reasonable :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. Could you mind explaining why using `&str` for `prev_key` does not work? Thanks.

Comment: Moreover `Option<String>` has the same size as `String` thanks to niche optimization.

Comment: @Shomy - `s` will go out of scope after each iteration of the for loop. but `prev_key` exists outside of the for loop too. So you could not assign `s` to `prev_key` and you can also not assign `data[0]` to `prev_key` since it is a reference of `s` to which the same rules apply

Comment: @TobiasS. Thanks very much. I have tried that using: `prev_key = data[0].clone()` but it does not work.

Comment: @Shomy - yes, when you do that, you are only cloning the *reference* to the str and not the str itself. But you need to clone the underlying string

Comment: @TobiasS.  Got it, thanks a lot for your nice answer. (I am quite new to Rust)